# regular expression: sum of positive fixed point decimal numbers

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I need help with this exercise.

Indicate the regular expression for the following Languages. Explain your  expression in one sentence and indicate the basis form of the alphabet. Indicate also every assumption you make.

i) Sums of positive fixed-point decimal numbers. The following Strings should exist in the Language:

e.g: 3.14 or also 3 + 4.2 + 7 + 1

I have a couple more exersices that are pretty similar but I guess if I get to understand this exercise I could try to do the others faster.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: what did you try ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of this but here it goes: I have this here L = {1,...,9,., +}

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Computer Science StackExchange! As it stands, it's hard to tell exactly what problem you're having answering the question, which could make it difficult to provide helpful answers. Please take a moment to edit your question to include additional information on what you've tried and where you think you might have gone wrong; ask targeted questions like whether some assumption holds or whether some argument is correct. For starters, you could move your proposed answer from the comments into the body and explain your reasoning, then ask about the first step about which ...

Comment: you're unsure. Otherwise, your question may be closed, in which case you could edit it later and flag it for reopening. Please visit the CS chat and/or CS Meta site if you would like to discuss how to improve this question. Thanks for your participation, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to identify the different kind of subexpression you have, and the regular expression should write itself.

Here you have a non-empty sum of decimal numbers, so the "outside shape" is $E=N(+N)^*$, where N is an expression for decimal numbers, and "+" is the symbol for addition.
Now we just have to detail N: it is a non-empty sequence of digits, with possibly one dot, which does not start with $0$ and does not end with $0$ if there is a dot.
For short let write D=0+1+2+...+9 the expression for 1 digit. here the "+" is the one from regular expression, meaning Union, not the addition symbol.
Also, the first digit should not be 0, and if there is a point, the last one should not be 0. So let's P=1+2+...+9 the expression for nonzero digits

We are now ready to write N:
N=PD*+PD*.D*P+0.D*P
It means that either we don't have a dot, and then we can end with 0, or we have a dot, and then we cannot ened with 0. There is also a special case for numbers like $0.345$.

By substituting the letters with their explicit expressions, you get the full explicit one for E.